# How to mask log4j2 log messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2(version - 2.5) and I am trying write a message converter plugin which will mask some of the know patterns of the log message.

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomeMasking",
        category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({"m"})
public class MyCustomFilteringLayout extends LogEventPatternConverter {
}
```

When I run my web application with this plugin then I see this warn message

> WARN Converter key 'm' is already mapped to 'class
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.MessagePatternConverter'. Sorry,
>   Dave, I can't let you do that! Ignoring plugin [class
>   MyCustomFilteringLayout].

After exploring log4j2 site I have found these references.

[Reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html)

> If multiple Converters specify the same ConverterKeys, then the load
>   order above determines which one will be used. For example, to
>   override the %date converter which is provided by the built-in
>   DatePatternConverter class, you would need to place your plugin in a
>   JAR file in the CLASSPATH ahead of log4j-core.jar. This is not
>   recommended; pattern ConverterKeys collisions will cause a warning to
>   be emitted. Try to use unique ConverterKeys for your custom pattern
>   converters.

I need help to understand how can I write my custom converters for m/msg. Is there any better way to do it?

**Additional Details:**
I have created shaded jar for MyCustomFilteringLayout. Reason why I am doing this way is that I want to keep masking logic separate from application.

---

Updated

I have created converter for my own key which looks like this,

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomeMasking",
            category = "Converter")
    @ConverterKeys({"cm"})
    public class MyCustomFilteringLayout extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    }
```

Here I can't write another converter for same ConverterKeys - cm?
Now my log4j2.xml has this pattern layout,

```
<PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %cm %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
```

Comment: Just wonder, can you simply use another key that is not taken by existing converter, and change your log pattern accordingly?

Comment: If I do that then I wont be able to write multiple converters for my key which I think will not solve my use case. My use case is, I want to mask certain patterns from the log messages and what I am thinking is to create many converters for different scenarios. Am I doing it wrong? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I am assuming you want to mask data in the log event, not prevent certain converter keys from being used?  Why not just write your own converter using a different converter key?  I don't really understand your statement that you wouldn't be able to write multiple converters. Perhaps you need to explain a bit better what you want to achieve.

Comment: @rgoers, Thanks for response. I have updated my question. I want to write multiple converters for same key for example key -"cm". In my log4j2.xml file I have defined pattern layout using this key,                         <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %cm %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update solves the problem and answers the question how to replace the built-in message converter with a custom one. It needs a unique key.

Sounds like you want to parameterize your pattern. Many patterns take an `options` parameter. You can use this to control behavior, so specifying %cm{key1} in your layout pattern will produce different results than %cm{key2}.

For an example of a converter that takes parameters, see the source code of the [MdcPatternConverter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/MdcPatternConverter.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is helpful.